# Selecting unique array value when comparing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a tool to recommend packages to customers depending on their choices. The customer will be presented with several groups of choices. I have an issue that when I am capturing the choices and than submitting at the end it is giving various options of choices.

For example the customer first is presented with 4 options, the minimum they can choose is 2 options. There is packages to be recommended if the customer chooses 2 options, 3options or 4 options.

If the customer chooses 4 options, at the end the result is showing all the answers for 2,3 & 4 options. I need to have the answer based on the largest selection.

This is how I am capturing the values and showing the answers:

```
   var mapAnswers = {
    "answerA": ["opt1", "opt2"],
    "answerB": ["opt3", "opt4"],
    "answerC": ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3", "opt4"]
};
$('#btn3').click(function () {        
    for (var i in mapAnswers) {
        var valid = true;
        for (var index in mapAnswers[i]) {
            console.log('index : '+index +' sel'+selections[mapAnswers[i][index]]);
            if (selections[mapAnswers[i][index]] !== true) valid = false;
        }
        console.log('test '+i+' valid ? '+valid);
        if (valid === true) $("#" + i).fadeIn("slow");
    }
```

A JSFiddle can also be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/J968n/

Comment: I don't exactly understand what the problem is? what do you expect the final output to be in your jsfiddle example?

Comment: @mario Does this look like your requirement? http://jsfiddle.net/J968n/2/ Or there is something more to be done?

Comment: @j809 This the perfect solution I required! - Many thanks indeed for your help. You can go ahead and write the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you can go for this code for `btn3` click:

```
$('#btn3').click(function () {    
        var choice='';
        for (var i in mapAnswers) {
            var valid = true;
            for (var index in mapAnswers[i]) {
                console.log('index : '+index +' sel'+selections[mapAnswers[i][index]]);
                if (selections[mapAnswers[i][index]] !== true) valid = false;
            }
            console.log('test '+i+' valid ? '+valid);
            if (valid === true) {
                choice=i;
            }
        }   
        if(choice!='')
            $("#" + choice).fadeIn("slow");

        $('#grp2').hide();
        $('#done').html(content);
        $('#grp3').fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J968n/2/)